# Is it possible to remove LinkedIn 'Accept invitation' button in Gmail inbox?

Tags: gmail, linkedin

When Gmail detects certain types of messages from certain sources (e.g. LinkedIn invitations), it provides shortcuts for actions it finds helpful, right in the inbox.

In some cases, however, these shortcuts are not only NOT helpful, but even annoying, as they are easy to click by accident, which causes the unwanted invitation to be accepted.

Is there a way to configure Gmail not to show these buttons?

I'm not looking for a browser-based solution, as I'm using, among others, [Kiwi for Gmail](https://www.kiwiforgmail.com/).

Answer (score 4):

you can disable hover actions in Gmail:
Settings -> General -> scroll to "Hover Actions" -> click on "Disable hover actions".

That way the "Accept invitation" button will at least be always visible and you will not click on it by mistake.

Solved by my friend Ranko, I am just posting the answer.

Comment: Though it is not a perfect solution, it makes the app behave in a more predictable manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adblock's future called **Block element**

- open such email
- click on Adblock Plus icon
- select **Block element**
- click on that button you want to block to highlight it
- hit **Add**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible, because I'm using Kiwi for Gmail, which does not support ABP.

Comment: @ohaleck that was not mentioned in your question... and also it makes this question off-topic I believe

Comment: Tho I appreciate your effort, I think that "Is there a way to configure Gmail..." makes the question clear enough to understand, that I'm interested in a solution within Gmail web app, which makes it container-agnostic.

Comment: @ohaleck Instead of getting defensive, you should follow up what *user0* says and edit your question. You are changing the goal posts. I have done the edit.

Comment: @JanDoggen your edit makes my question specific to Kiwi for Gmail, which is not true. My question was stated perfectly clear: I'm looking for a way to configure Gmail, not to hack it as user0 suggests, and I'm not limiting the use case to just one client.

Comment: @ohaleck You can revert my edit. Click on the *edited* text and choose *revert edit* - or edit it yourself again.

Comment: @JanDoggen I did, to reflect truth better.